# Anyone here familiar with the Ethereum block chain developers program/certification?

Tags: blockchain

I read about the block chain developers course with the goal of creating about 6000ish certified Ethereum developers.  I am trying to find out if anyone has actually done the course? I am a Java and RoR developer and would like to branch out in to crypto currency. Thanks

Comment: External link to the course details: http://b9lab.com/blockchain-training/